# Unexpected results from Additive and Subtractive effects passes when combining the results of Three.js EffectComposers

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js

I'm doing some postprocessing in Three.js using EffectComposers and shader passes, and am getting some strange behavior when I begin to combine the WebGLRenderTargets (renderTarget2) from these composers in further composers. I have five composers: three render scenes (`lightComposer`, `motifsComposer`, `selectedMotifsComposer`), and two do some combining of the resulting scenes via their composers' render targets (`motifsCompositeComposer`, `finalComposer`).

`motifsComposer` and `selectedMotifsComposer` render the same scene; however, they differ with a change to one of the uniforms so that I can use different effects on motifs that have been clicked by a user. They both work fine independently and even combine as expected with an additive shader pass in the `motifCompositeComposer`. `lightComposer` also works as expected when I render it on its own.

However, when I do a subtractive shader pass to combine the render targets from `lightComposer` and `motifsCompositeComposer` in the `finalComposer` I only see the results of the `lightComposer` render target. Further, I'll attach some sample images below of what happens when I add and remove components and change their order. I'm hoping you can help me piece together what's happening here. I've been trying many, many permutations of the code and can't seem to crack this issue.

My current assumption is that there's an alpha issue at play, but I'm not sure how to address that. Here is the [AdditiveBlendShader](https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/js/shaders/AdditiveBlendShader.js) script I use, written by Lee Stemkoski. For the subtractive blend I made an alternate copy of this script in which I change `gl_FragColor = texel1 + texel2;` in the fragment shader to: `gl_FragColor = texel1 - texel2;`.

**Composer setup:**

```
// Light Composer
lightCloud = (a PointCloud with a BufferGeometry and ShaderMaterial);
lightScene.add( lightCloud );
var renderLight = new THREE.RenderPass( lightScene, lightCamera );
lightComposer.addPass( renderLight );

// Motif Point Cloud
gridOfMotifs = (a PointCloud with a BufferGeometry and ShaderMaterial);
motifScene.add( gridOfMotifs );
var renderMotifs = new THREE.RenderPass( motifScene, motifCamera );

// Motifs Composer
motifsComposer.addPass( renderMotifs );

// Selected Motifs Composer
gridOfMotifs.material.uniforms.uRenderSelectedMotifs.value = 1;
selectedMotifsComposer.addPass( renderMotifs );
selectedMotifsComposer.addPass( effectBloom );

// Motifs Composite Composer
effectAdditive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse1" ].value = motifsComposer.renderTarget2;
effectAdditive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse2" ].value = selectedMotifsComposer.renderTarget2;
motifsCompositeComposer.addPass( effectAdditive );   

// Final Composer
effectSubtractive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse1" ].value = lightComposer.renderTarget2;
effectSubtractive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse2" ].value = motifsCompositeComposer.renderTarget2;
finalComposer.addPass( effectSubtractive );
finalComposer.addPass( effectCopy );
effectCopy.renderToScreen = true;
```

**The render call looks like this:**

```
renderer.clear();

lightComposer.render();

gridOfMotifs.material.uniforms.uRenderSelectedMotifs.value = 0;
motifsComposer.render();

gridOfMotifs.material.uniforms.uRenderSelectedMotifs.value = 1;
selectedMotifsComposer.render();

motifsCompositeComposer.render();

finalComposer.render();
```

1) As a baseline, this is the result of the lightComposer (performing as expected):

[image]

2) This is the result of the `motifsCompositeComposer` that merges the results of both the `motifsComposer` and the `selectedMotifsComposer` (selected motifs have a  and light glow from a bloom pass). This performs as expected:

[image]

3) However, when I render straight through to the `finalComposer`, with the render target of the `motifsCompositeComposer` subtracted from the render target of the `lightComposer` (should make black motifs on a white light cloud) I get only the results of the `lightComposer` shown in 1) above. If I reverse the two textures in the the subtractive pass in `finalComposer` so that the render target of the `lightComposer` is subtracted from the render target of the `motifsCompositeComposer`, the screen is black.

4) If I modify the script by commenting out the texture assignment (marked with `***`) below I get the image that follows, showing only the unselected motifs (see the holes where the selected motifs would be).

```
// Motifs Composite Composer
effectAdditive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse1" ].value = motifsComposer.renderTarget2;
effectAdditive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse2" ].value = selectedMotifsComposer.renderTarget2;
motifsCompositeComposer.addPass( effectAdditive );   

// Final Composer
// effectSubtractive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse1" ].value = lightComposer.renderTarget2; <---***commented out
effectSubtractive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse2" ].value = motifsCompositeComposer.renderTarget2;
finalComposer.addPass( effectSubtractive );
finalComposer.addPass( effectCopy );
effectCopy.renderToScreen = true;
```

[image]

5a) The closest I manage to get too what I actually want to happen is when I comment out one of the textures in the final subtractive pass (marked again with `***`), which subtracts the selected motifs (glowing ones) from the light cloud, but wholly misses the subtracting out the larger grid of motifs:

```
// Motifs Composite Composer
effectAdditive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse1" ].value = motifsComposer.renderTarget2;
effectAdditive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse2" ].value = selectedMotifsComposer.renderTarget2;
motifsCompositeComposer.addPass( effectAdditive );   

// Final Composer
effectSubtractive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse1" ].value = lightComposer.renderTarget2;
//effectSubtractive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse2" ].value = motifsCompositeComposer.renderTarget2; <---***commented out
finalComposer.addPass( effectSubtractive );
finalComposer.addPass( effectCopy );
effectCopy.renderToScreen = true;
```

[image]

5b) Alternately I can reverse the assignments of the two textures in the additive pass in `motifCompositeComposer` and get the larger grid of motifs subtracted from the light cloud, but not the selected (glowing) motifs:

```
// Motifs Composite Composer
effectAdditive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse2" ].value = motifsComposer.renderTarget2; // <---***reversed assignment of the textures
effectAdditive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse1" ].value = selectedMotifsComposer.renderTarget2; // <---***reversed assignment of the textures
motifsCompositeComposer.addPass( effectAdditive );   

// Final Composer
effectSubtractive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse1" ].value = lightComposer.renderTarget2;
//effectSubtractive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse2" ].value = motifsCompositeComposer.renderTarget2; <---***commented out
finalComposer.addPass( effectSubtractive );
finalComposer.addPass( effectCopy );
effectCopy.renderToScreen = true;
```

[image]

6) Finally, and perhaps most informatively, though I can't discern what it means: if I make the following changes, the selected motifs (glowing ones) form a mask that lets through a reverse image of the light cloud:

```
// Motifs Composite Composer
effectAdditive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse2" ].value = motifsComposer.renderTarget2; // <---***reversed assignment of the textures
effectAdditive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse1" ].value = selectedMotifsComposer.renderTarget2; // <---***reversed assignment of the textures
motifsCompositeComposer.addPass( effectAdditive );   

// Final Composer
effectSubtractive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse2" ].value = lightComposer.renderTarget2; // <---***Changed to tDiffuse2
//effectSubtractive.uniforms[ "tDiffuse2" ].value = motifsCompositeComposer.renderTarget2; <---***commented out
finalComposer.addPass( effectSubtractive );
finalComposer.addPass( effectCopy );
effectCopy.renderToScreen = true;
```

[image]

In the end, I'm aiming to get the full grid of motifs subtracted (appearing in black) from the white light cloud. You help here is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! Found it. In the `finalComposer` I needed to set the render target of `motifsCompositeComposer` to `renderTarget1` not `renderTarget2`. I'm not sure, but I think this is because the additive pass in `motifsCompositeComposer` is not followed by a copypass, which would swap the result to the second render target(?!).

```
effectSubtractive.uniforms.tDiffuse1.value = lightComposer.renderTarget2;
effectSubtractive.uniforms.tDiffuse2.value = motifsCompositeComposer.renderTarget1; // <---***Note the change to renderTarget1
finalComposer.addPass( effectSubtractive );
finalComposer.addPass( effectCopy );
```